# Magento 2 not writing to anything to log files

Tags: magento2

I have fresh magento install, created respective files under var/log,

ran
`bin/magento setup:config:set --enable-debug-logging=true`

use `\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger` in  my code `$this->logger->info('600');`
leaves all of the log files empty

Answer (score 1):

There are some possibilities, but base on your description, I think:

1. Your server is out of storage/space.
2. Your var/log permission is not configured properly, please grant writable access. or to ease your issue, you can try to change the permission to 777 for var directory `chmod -R 777 var`, then when all sorted by this solution, you can revert the permission and just grant write permission to it.

Comment: You are almost right, but the problem turned out to be docker sync with the source, I have them written inside docker container but not in the project folder

Comment: ahh... that's different issue then, did the same mistake sometimes :), thanks for confirming

Answer (score 0):

You can log anything by using this logs :

**With Magento 2.4.4 & plus versions use below code:**

```
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/testing.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Test the log');
$logger->info(var_dump($yourVariable));
```

**For Magento 2.4.2 & lower versions:**

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Custom message'); 
$logger->info(var_dump($yourVariable));
```

Comment: This is what I'm using, this is not a solution

Comment: You can check the permission of the Var/Log directory and you can use the debugger